# Determinant using Leibniz formula

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

$$\begin{matrix}
        * & * & *&*&* \\
        *&*&*&*&*\\
        0&0&0&*&* \\
        0&0&0&*&* \\
        0&0&0&*&* \\
        \end{matrix}$$
all the asterisk's belong to real numbers

The question is show $determinant=0$ by contemplating the Leibniz formula.

I know its zero intuitively and aware it has $5!$ terms in the formula but how can i prove it without calculating.

any help appreciated

Comment: Note that a proof could also just use that the bottom three rows must be linearly dependent since they are all elements of the two-dimensional subspace $\{(0,0,0,a,b)|a,b\in\mathbb R\}$.

Comment: @AlexR I know that part of not being linearly independent however i am only interested in showing using Leibniz formula for the time being

Comment: All fine, that's why I only commented with this ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider an arbitrary, fixed summand in [Leibniz's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_determinants). It must contain an element from each of the last three rows of the matrix. But these elements have to be in three distint columns. So one of them will be in one of the first three columns, thus zero.

Comment: got it thanks for the help

Comment: You're welcome!